# Custom Input Fields with Stripes Payment-Element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I am using stripe in a next.js application in order to accept one time payments and so far have been following the standard tutorial for Stripe Elements.

The way it works is that I create a `PaymentIntent` on first render:

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
        // using nextjs api route here:
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/create-payment-intent', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
    }, []);
```

This gives me a clientSecret, which is store in state. Then, Stripes Payment Element Component is being displayed and on submit, I am calling `confirmPayment`:

```
const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
                // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
                return_url:
                    'http://localhost:3001/confirm'
            }
        });
```

My problem is that I want to also grab the users name and email address, but I have no clue where I would capture those and where to send them to in stripe?

I guess it would make the most sense to create a new customer in stripe and add `name` and `email` to that customer object. But since almost everything is happening in the frontend (or at least not on *my* backend), I don't understand how to do that? I could do it when I create the `PaymentIntent` and send back the `clientSecret` - but then I would potentially be creating customers, even when they don't complete the payment intent.

*PS: I know that this question has been asked a few times before, but Stripes API has changed quite significantly since then.*

Comment: From what I can gather thus far, it still seems that in order to capture the name and email, you'd have to create your own fields, validate them, then add them into the billing info.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own input fields on your frontend for the  customer's name and email address.

If you don't want to create a customer before successful payment, one way to go about it is to :

1. Pass the input values into `name` and `email` in [stripe.confirmPayment.confirmParams.payment_method_data.billing_details](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-confirmParams-payment_method_data-billing_details).

Example

```
stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
       return_url: 'https://example.com/',
        payment_method_data : {
          billing_details : {
            name : "jenny rosen",
            email : "test@example.com" 
          }
        }
      },
    });
```

2. When you receive the `payment_intent.succeeded` [webhook event](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks), the event will contain the billing details which you passed in.

payment_intent.succeeded example event

```
...
 "charges": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "ch_...",
          "object": "charge",
          "amount": 200000,
          "amount_captured": 200000,
          "amount_refunded": 0,
          "amount_updates": [
          ],
          "application": null,
          "application_fee": null,
          "application_fee_amount": null,
          "balance_transaction": "txn_...",
          "billing_details": {
            "address": {
              "city": null,
              "country": "US",
              "line1": null,
              "line2": null,
              "postal_code": null,
              "state": null
            },
            "email": "test@example.com",
            "name": "jenny rosen",
            "phone": null
          },
...
```

3. You can then create the Customer.

Comment: Is there no way to grab and display the payment method data at the redirected `return_url` - i.e. without using a webhook? From the documentation it seems like it should be but when I inspect `payment_data` on my Payment Intent it's null.